# Conditional independence $a\bot b|\emptyset$ for $p(a,b,c) = p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)$

Tags: probability

Suppose a graph

[image]

which factorizes: $p(a,b,c) = p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)$

How can I show that

$p(a,b) = p(a) \sum_c p(c|a) p(b|c) = p(a)p(b|a)$

as it is not shown in my textbook

[image]

Comment: the question which is marked as the original is deleted for me... :/

Comment: I deleted it a few minutes ago

Comment: I might be wrong, as I am not mathematician, but I think you can take the general form of the chain rule:
$p(a,b) &= p(a)\sum\limits_{c} {p(c|a)p(b|a,c)}$

Comment: Please add to your question what you have attempted and where you have becoming stuck in trying to answer this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_c p(c|a) p(b|c)=\sum_c \frac{p(a,c)}{p(a)} \frac{p(b,c)}{p(c)} \ne\frac{p(a)}{p(a)} p(b)$$
Nota: I have trouble imagining which mistake you did which led you to believe the $\ne$ sign above should actually be an $=$ sign.

Comment: Well as I said in my question I am aware that this is $\neq$ but could you explain to me why? $\sum_c \frac{p(a,c)}{p(a)} = 1$ but why is $\sum_c \frac{p(b,c)}{p(c)} \neq p(b)$ ?

Comment: First, why should this sum be equal to $p(b)$? Second, even if it was, this would not imply what you write. Hence, as I said, I have trouble imagining the mistake you did.

Comment: I really have no idea what I should ask except.. what is $ \sum_c p(c) = ?$ it seems like I am unable to formalize my question in a way that others can understand it. I think my question is very clear. I wonder how $p(a,b) = p(a)p(b|a)$ can be shown ..

Comment: Of course $\sum\limits_cp(c)=1$. How should this be even *related* to $\sum\limits_c\frac{p(b,c)}{p(c)}$, I have no idea. Say, have you ever checked some examples on probability spaces of size 2 or 3?

Comment: so is $\sum_c \frac{p(b,c)}{p(c)} = p(b)$?

Comment: No, your question is not how $p(a,b)=p(a)p(b|a)$ can be shown, your question is "What am I doing wrong here?" If you want to ask the question "how $p(a,b)=p(a)p(b|a)$ can be shown" then the answer is: "it is not *shown*, it is a definition, so grab a textbook".

Comment: "so is $\sum\limits_c\frac{p(b,c)}{p(c)}=p(b)$?" Of course not, as already said.

Comment: okay if $\sum_c p(b,c) = p(b)$ and $\sum_c p(c) = 1$ then why is $\sum_c \frac{p(b,c)}{p(c)} \neq p(b)$ ? You see, my problem is that I don't get that ..

Comment: Because $$\sum_c\frac{p(b,c)}{p(c)}\ne\frac{\sum\limits_cp(b,c)}{\sum\limits_cp(c)}.$$

Comment: Okay and would you be so kind and tell me how $p(a,b) = p(a) \sum_c p(c|a) p(b|c) = p(a)p(b|a)$ can be shown? I know you said that this is a *definition* but in that case I really don't understand this notation at all .. I have a factorization for $p(a,b,c)$ and by $p(a,b)$ in that context this means to me "*what is the joint probability of $a$ and $b$ for that graph*". This must be somehow "showable" ..

Comment: Yes the identity $p(a,b)=p(a)p(b|a)$ is a definition, the middle term is not useful to know that LHS = RHS.

Comment: When it comes to probability I always mix up the definitions .. the textbook does not explicitly state that this is just a definition and I assumed that I can somehow show that $p(a,b) = p(a)p(b|a)$ for that graph if $p(c)$ is not observed.. but thank you for going through that with me!

Comment: Wouldn't that be a way to show it?

\begin{align}
p(a,b) &= p(a) \sum_c p(c|a) p(b|c) \\
&= \sum_c p(a,b,c) \\
&= p(a) \frac{\sum_c p(a,b,c)}{p(a)}\\
&= p(a) \frac{p(a,b)}{p(a)}\\
&= p( a)p(b|a) 
\end{align}

Comment: This is making circles since the very last = sign is the only one necessary--hence, as I said in my previous comment, there is no proof here but a definition.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your patience!